# I want to pass the current "UserID" into the database in an Insert statement. php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am currently working on a project where a user can review a product then when they "Submit", the UserID & PreferenceID are picked up from the DB & passed into another table in the DB using php/mysql.

The UserID is displayed when they are logged in.

Here is some of the code:

```
$user_id = $_GET['CustomerID'];
$DissCustPref_PrefID = $_GET['DissCustPref_PrefID'];
$Cigar_CigarID = $_GET['Cigar_CigarID'];
$SmokingTime = $_GET['SmokingTime'];
$CigarFlavour = $_GET['CigarFlavour'];
$FlavourStrength = $_GET['FlavourStrength'];
$Body = $_GET['Body'];
$AfterTaste = $_GET['AfterTaste'];
$Age = $_GET['Age'];
$ValueForMoney = $_GET['ValueForMoney'];
$OverallRating = $_GET['OverallRating'];

$user_id = $row->CustomerID;
print "<br>User ID: ";
echo($user_id);

$query = "INSERT INTO DissReview values
('null','.$user_id','.$DissCustPref_PrefID','$Cigar_CigarID',
 '$SmokingTime','$CigarFlavour','$FlavourStrength','$Body',
 '$AfterTaste','$Age','$ValueForMoney','$OverallRating')";
```

At the moment the URL looks like: http://www.somewebsite/foldername/Login/PreviousReviews.php?CustomerID=%24user_id&CustPref_PrefID=%24PrefID&CigarID=2&SmokingTime=2&CigarFlavour=6&FlavourStrength=5&Body=4&AfterTaste=2&Age=2&ValueForMoney=2&OverallRating=4

as you can see it is not getting the userID or the Preference ID.

It should look like CustomerID=1.... and so on.
 I have tried using '".UserID."' but this does not work.

Any suggetions?

EDIT ------ Here is the form used to send the data:

Please add your review of the cigar here!

CIGAR

```
    <textarea style="display:none;"></textarea>


 <!--This is the rating for the amount of time it took to smoke.-->
 <p> Units below are represented in minutes.</p>

 <select name="SmokingTime">

     <option value="0"> Please Select an Option</option>
     <option value="1">15</option>
     <option value="2">30</option>
     <option value="3">45</option>
     <option value="4">60</option>
     <option value="5">61+</option>

 </select>


 <div id="FChart" class="FChart">
     <p> <img src="cigar-flavors-wheel.png" alt="Cigar Flavour Wheel" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></p>
 </div>

 <!--This is the rating for how the cigar tastes.-->
 <p> Please select what the cigar tastes like.</p>
 <select name="CigarFlavour">
     <option value="0"> Please Select an Option</option>
     <option value="1">Flowers</option>
     <option value="2">Plants</option>
     <option value="3">Herbs and Spices</option>
     <option value="4">Earths and Minerals</option>
     <option value="5">Fruit</option>
     <option value="6">Nuts</option>
     <option value="7">Chocolate</option>
     <option value="8">Coffee</option>
     <option value="9">Cream</option>
     <option value="10">Leather</option>
 </select>

 <!--This is the rating for the strength of the flavour.-->
 <p> Please select how strong the taste is.</p>
 <select name="FlavourStrength">
     <option value="0"> Please Select an Option</option>
     <option value="1">Very Weak</option>
     <option value="2">Weak</option>
     <option value="3">Mild</option>
     <option value="4">Strong</option>
     <option value="5">Very Strong</option>
 </select>

 <!--This is the rating for how the cigar is: Medium body for example.-->
 <p> Please Select the body of the cigar.</p>
 <select name="Body">
     <option value="0"> Please Select an Option</option>
     <option value="1">Mild</option>
     <option value="2">Medium</option>
     <option value="3">Medium Full</option>
     <option value="4">Full</option>
 </select>

 <!--This is the rating for the strength of the after taste.-->
 <p> Please Describe the Strength of the After taste.</p>
 <select name="AfterTaste">
     <option value="0"> Please Select an Option</option>
     <option value="1">Very Weak</option>
     <option value="2">Weak</option>
     <option value="3">Mild</option>
     <option value="4">Strong</option>
     <option value="5">Very Strong</option>
 </select>

 <!--This is the rating for the age of the cigar.-->
 <p> Please select a rough age of the cigar.</p>
 <select name="Age">
     <option value="0"> Please Select an Option</option>
     <option value="1">6 Months</option>
     <option value="2">1 Year</option>
     <option value="3">2 Years</option>
     <option value="4">3 Years</option>
     <option value="5">4 years</option>
     <option value="6">4+ years</option>
 </select>

 <!--This is the rating for the value for money.-->
 <p> Please Describe the value for money aspect.</p>
 <select name="ValueForMoney">
     <option value="0"> Please Select an Option</option>
     <option value="1">Very Poor</option>
     <option value="2">Poor</option>
     <option value="3">Reasonable</option>
     <option value="4">Good</option>
     <option value="5">Very Good</option>
 </select>

 <!--This is the overall rating of the cigar.-->
 <p> Please select an overall rating of the cigar.</p>
 <select name="OverallRating">
     <option value="0"> Please Select an Option</option>
     <option value="1">Very Poor</option>
     <option value="2">Poor</option>
     <option value="3">Reasonable</option>
     <option value="4">Good</option>
     <option value="5">Very Good</option>
 </select>
```

">

I am echoing the $UserID as debugging to see if it is picking it up.

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting with code?

Comment: you set `user_id = $_GET['CustomerID'];` and then `$user_id = $row->CustomerID;`

Comment: I don't get an error instead of the php picking up the UserID for whoever is logged it, it just gets the variabel name $UserID.   If you are User1 it should pick up that you are User 1 and insert that into the table. I can give you the URl for the site if you want

Comment: Please add the form you used to submit this data.

Answer (score 0):

It just show the `$user_id`

because you have this code :

```
echo($user_id);
```

And you should have some controls on user inputs ! hackers can easily do some Sql injections.
for example use :

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($input);
```

Comment: I've tried a number of different methods to try an pass the UserID along with the rest of the form with no luck. I am echoing the ID just to see that it is picking up the ID for whoever is logged in.